# ViewCube rotation of 90 degrees

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

i`m wondering there is possibility to make 90 degrees rotation using JS action like ViewCube arrow action:

[image]

i know that i could manipulate using

```
viewer.setViewCube("left")
```

but to get my purposes i have to do it once for left and then second time on top again. But between of this steps i need to wait for end of animation of first operation. The best for me would be do that 90 degrees rotation, but i didn`t found any API call of it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a face combination to that method, see from the comments in the source code:

```
 /**
 * Set the face of ViewCube and apply camera transformation according to it.
 * @param {string} face - The face name of ViewCube. The name can contain multiple face names,
 * the format should be `"[front/back], [top/bottom], [left/right]"`.
 */
 Viewer3D.prototype.setViewCube = function(face)
```

Comment: yes, I know that, but result of invoke this method with 'left/top' ('top left', 'top, left') parameter is different than invoke it twice with 'left' and 'top'. I want to rotate object (building) to see only top with left rotation (90 degrees), not top and left. That's way the arrow was best, but i cannot find method for it

Comment: If you want more flexibility you should modify the camera parameters directly through viewer.navigation methods, take a look at this article for more details: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-skybox-and-camera-animation